# I need a formula to sort a list in a regular alternating pattern according to numeric values assigned to each item

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I’m working in Google sheets and need a formula to transform the information in columns A and B into a single column with the pattern shown in column C. The idea in Column C is to get as equal a distribution of the items from Column A as possible, with each item alternating with the other items in the list and repeating in the list for the number of times given in column B. At the bottom of the list, 5 cells always need to be added with the text in A4. I’m definitely a novice with formulas and don’t have any idea how to even start with this. Is it possible?

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will repeat items in `A2:A` each `B2:B` times, and sort them into a random order, except the one item in `A2:A` where `B2:B` is blank. The one item will be repeated `5` times at the end of the list.

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    sort( 
      vlookup( 
        sequence(sum(B2:B), 1, 0), 
        { sumif(row(B2:B), "<" & row(B2:B), B2:B), A2:A }, 
        2, 
        true 
      ), 
      randarray(sum(B2:B)), true 
    ); 
    flatten( if( sequence(1, 5), +filter(A2:A, isblank(B2:B)) ) ) 
  } 
)
```

To get tomato, apple, melon in the order they appear in the list, replace `randarray(sum(B2:B))` with `sequence(sum(B2:B))`.

To get the vegetables in the alternating order you show in the question, you can use a custom function, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    RepeatRows(A2:A, B2:B); 
    flatten( if( sequence(1, 5), +filter(A2:A, isblank(B2:B)) ) ) 
  } 
)
```

This custom function should go to **Extensions > Apps Script**:

```
/**
* Repeats each row in rows_to_repeat times_to_repeat times, in an alternating fashion.
*
* @param {A2:B4} rows_to_repeat The values to repeat row-by-row.
* @param {D2:D4} times_to_repeat The number of times to repeat each row in rows_to_repeat.
* @return {Object[][]} The repeated rows.
* @customfunction
*/
function RepeatRows(rows_to_repeat, times_to_repeat) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 24 January 2022
  //  - return rows in an alternating order, see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/162501/269219
  let rows = rows_to_repeat;
  let times = times_to_repeat;
  if (!Array.isArray(rows)) {
    rows = [[rows]];
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(times)) {
    times = [[times]];
  }
  let array = [];
  rows.forEach((row, index) => {
    array.push([]);
    const numRows = times[index] ? times[index][0] : times[0][0];
    for (let i = 0; i < Number(numRows); i++) {
      array[index].push(row[0]);
    }
  });
  return transposeArray_(array).flat();
}


/**
* Transposes a 2D array.
*
* @param {Object[][]} array The array to transpose.
* @return {Object[][]} The transposed array, or the single value as is.
*/
function transposeArray_(array) {
  var result = [];
  for (var row = 0, numRows = array.length; row < numRows; row++) {
    for (var column = 0, numColumns = array[row].length; column < numColumns; column++) {
      if (!result[column]) {
        result[column] = [];
      }
      result[column][row] = array[row][column];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @doubleunary. But I do need it to be not random if possible. (I should have been more specific about this.) The order I need for the elements is the order in column A. So, Tomato, Orange, Melon iterated that way going down the column for as many times as each number in column B specifies. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: Edited the answer. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, rather than vegetables. Also show your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted - amazing stuff. Thank you so much for your help @doubleunary!

Comment: doubleunary, I was wondering if I could get your help on a modification to this. I have your script running in this spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kLeCbpiQH9aJVtAAqpox_lTnYvgcxGgTO7nvxkCynVQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In each of columns B to O it sorts first A2 to A6 in an alternating pattern according to the numbers in each column and then A7 to A9 in the same pattern and then adds the word Extra 100 times on the end. What I’d like to do is reverse the order of the sorting for A2 to A6 and then reverse the order of the sorting for A7 to A9 followed by the word Extra 100 times in alternate columns. Column Q shows an example (manually entered) of what I want to achieve using the information in column L. Is this possible? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: Sorry - I'll get better at this! I'll repost. Thanks.